# How to convert 3GP files to MP3 with Node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ffmpeg

I'm making a recorder app with React-Native and the audio file will be sent from the Android device to Node backend. I am able to retrieve it with Multer S3, however I want to also transform the file into an MP3 or MPEG, so that it is playable on any device. I've looked into [FFMPEG](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ffmpeg), but that seems to only be a solution for videos.

What are my options here?

Answer (score 0):

use [fluent-ffmpeg](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fluent-ffmpeg/v/1.7.0) to convert video to mp3 format

```
var ffmpeg = require('fluent-ffmpeg');

 function convertInternal(video,sampleRate,mp3path) {
      return ffmpeg(video, {
        nolog: true,
      })
        // options to convert to mp3
        .withAudioCodec('libmp3lame')
        .audioFrequency(sampleRate)
        .toFormat('mp3').saveToFile(mp3path);
    }
```